# How to store complex records for referencing historical revisions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table on my database that outlines complex processes in a [work breakdown structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_breakdown_structure) (similar to what's used to create Gantt charts).  There are multiple rows for a particular process, each row outlining a hierarchical step of a particular process.

I then have a table with some product types, each being linked to a particular process.  When an order for a particular product is placed - it is to be manufactured with the associated process.

In my situation, the processes can be dynamic (steps added or removed, for example).

I'm curious as to what the best way to capture current and historical revisions of each process is, such that even though a process may have evolved over time - I can historically go back to a particular order and determine what the process looked like at that time.

I'm sure there are multiple ways to go about this, using logging or triggers with a new history table - but I've had no experience doing something like this and I'd like to know what worked well for others.

Comment: One approach is to copy the entire structure of a process any time an edit is made, and save a new version. You can store a link to the original process if you want to be able to view the history. Links to an historic process will always be correct as you don't change them.

Comment: 1. Easiest and simplest way would be to log snapshot of the process once it is being saved, it is not space efficient, but easy to populate and retrieve. 

2. Another way is row by row history but it is requires more effort due to the fact that you need track changes on the application layer and propagate them to database as steps of insert, delete and update to the tree hierarchy.

Data retrieval will require to select last item before specified date for each individual item in the tree.